# Group formation with owner and members using mongoid based databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, associations, mongoid

In my rails app, I have a user model with other fields and associations in it. Now I want, my users can make many projects and a project can have many users as members in it. And, the owner of the project is the one who created it. So, the whole scenario is Users can be owner or member and can be part of many projects. I have made my user using devise and I am using mongodb as my database. My user model has already many fields and associations in it, now I am struck at defining associations and relations for the above mentioned problem.

I have found one similar article with Active record: https://coderwall.com/p/rqjjca/creating-a-scoped-invitation-system-for-rails

But I want to execute all using mongoid and rails 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for above problem is not so hard, as mongoid allows has_and_belongs_to_many association in rails, we can associate as:

In my users.rb:

`has_and_belongs_to_many: projects`

In my projects.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many: users
```

Later we can also define roles of users as admin and member according to our requirement.